# How to remove the id's for the deleted rows in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, which has 5 rows. And the id was starting from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. But then in the rails console I did Model.delete_all. Now if I am trying to insert the new records, the id is starting from 6 instead of 1. I want the new records to have the id starting from 1 as I deleted the previous records. How to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Hey you can truncate your table using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name")` instead of `delete_all`

Comment: @gates that's really not needed. Those comes from auto increament of sequences.. But have a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements/reset_pk_sequence%21 .

Answer (score 1):

If we want to restart the id sequence, so we may use this:

For Postgres:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(Model.table_name)
```

For SQLite

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update sqlite_sequence set seq = 1 where name = '#{Model.table_name}';")
```

Comment: Hi, I am using postgres DB. My model name is PackageType and my table name is package_types. When I did the followinf in the console ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(PackageType.package_types). I get No method error. Please clarify.